Как передать значимый тип в ViewModel что бы при изменении его, в ViewModel он изменялся тоже и срабатывал binding?
Я реализую в своем приложении выпадающее меню, в котором находится список кнопок.
Через ItemsControl и класс ActionButton(String ImgUrl, string Text) я отрисовываю список в xaml.
Условно в ViewModel выпадающего меню мы передаем некоторые классы с INotifyPropertyChanged
И допустим нужно сделать такую возможность, что бы когда в классе с INotifyPropertyChanged изменялось некоторое свойство, то кнопка могла отреагировать на это и поменять текст на дополнительный(Или любой заданный другой)
Для реализации INotifyPropertyChanged я использую библиотеку CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel
Перейдем немного к коду:
    public partial class DropdownMenuViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Server Server;
        public Profile Profile;
        public ObservableCollection<ActionButton> Buttons { get; set; }

        public DropdownMenuViewModel(Server server, Profile profile)
        {
            Server = server;
            Profile = profile;
            Buttons = new ObservableCollection<ActionButton>
            {
                new ActionButton("Img", "Включить сервер", Server.IsEnabled, "Выключить сервер"),
                new ActionButton("Img", "Войти", Profile.IsOnline, "Выйти"),
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class Server : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isEnabled;
    }

    public partial class Profile : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isOnline;
    }

    public class ActionButton(string imageUrl, string text, bool? condition = null, string? additionalText = null)
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = imageUrl;

        public string Text { get; set; } = text;

        public bool? Condition { get; set; } = condition;

        public string? AdditionalText { get; set; } = additionalText;
    }

И код UserControl:
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Condition}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding AdditionalText}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="-----" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

То есть я хочу добится такого поведения, что при изменении переменных внутри любого класса (Server.IsEnabled или Profile.IsOnline к примеру) внутри соответствующих элементов изменялся текст
Server.IsEnabled --> ActionButton.Condition --> Изменения в xaml
Но так как мы передаем не ссылки на переменные, то когда эти переменные изменяется в классе, изменения не изменяются в ActionButton.
Передать bool из класса используя ref нельзя.
(Property 'x' access returns temporary value. 'ref' argument must be an assignable variable, field, or an array element)
Единственное к чему я пришел это использование интерфейса, который содержит bool переменную
Измененный код:
    public partial class DropdownMenuViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Server Server;
        public Profile Profile;
        public ObservableCollection<ActionButton> Buttons { get; set; }

        public DropdownMenuViewModel(Server server, Profile profile)
        {
            Server = server;
            Profile = profile;
            Buttons = new ObservableCollection<ActionButton>
            {
                new ActionButton("Img", "Включить сервер", Server, "Выключить"),
                new ActionButton("Img", "Войти", Profile, "Выйти"),
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class Server : ObservableObject, IConditionChanged
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Condition))]
        private bool _isEnabled;

        public bool Condition => IsEnabled;
    }


    public partial class Profile : ObservableObject, IConditionChanged
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Condition))]
        private bool _isOnline;

        public bool Condition => IsOnline;
    }

    public class ActionButton(string imageUrl, string text, IConditionChanged? condition = null, string? additionalText = null)
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = imageUrl;

        public string Text { get; set; } = text;

        public IConditionChanged? Condition { get; set; } = condition;

        public string? AdditionalText { get; set; } = additionalText;

        public bool IsHasCondition => Condition != null;
    }

    public interface IConditionChanged
    {
        bool Condition { get; }
    }

И код XAML:
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Aqua">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHasCondition}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHasCondition}" Value="True" />
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Condition.Condition}" Value="False" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsHasCondition}" Value="True" />
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Condition.Condition}" Value="True" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding AdditionalText}" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="-----" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

Как реализовать этот функционал правильным образом?
Является ли использование в классах которые являются представлением обьекта(model) использование INotifyPropertyChanged обобщенной практикой?

Прочитайте про IObservable. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=net-7.0

ObservableCollection замените на BindingList и подпишитесь на его событие изменения, которое вам скажет кто изменился и как изменился, ну а уже по этому событию дергайте свойство, которое будет менять UI. Но вообще, у вас странная реализация всего этого, зачем вы разбиваете вот так на разные классы логику, я не знаю... C# очень любит наследования, интерфейсы, абстракции, и так далее, в чем проблема сделать интерфейс/абстрактный класс, который будет описывать "кнопку меню", а от нее уже наследовать всякие Server/Profile и т.д. Также очень странно разбивать по данным, а не по типу...

@EvgeniyZ Извините, я только изучаю mvvm и пока что мало использую механизмы наследования, не могли бы вы подробнее обьяснить что вы имеете в виду "разбивать по данным, а не по типу"? "зачем вы разбиваете вот так на разные классы логику, я не знаю" - Я лишь показал абстрактный пример, суть которого при изменении переменной значимого типа внутри внешних классов уведомлять нужные места об обновлении данных для привязки данных.
(как я уже понял используют IObservable или как вы выше указали BindingList)
Был бы рад увидеть более подробный ответ с примером кода

Смотрите, вот меню, это что? Это набор кнопок, текста, разделителей, "групп", правильно? То есть меню может содержать "кнопку", может содержать "дерево" открывающее при нажатие подменю с кнопками, может содержать простой "текст", ну а также может содержать "разделитель", который отделит один раздел меню от другого. Это стандартные "типы" любого меню. У каждого "типа" имеются свои органы управления, свои свойства, которые отвечают за конкретный вид и конкретную логику, они не завязаны на "данных".

Теперь посмотрите на свой код, у вас есть "сервер", "профиль" - это все данные, которыми должны быть заполнены "типы", но ни как не наоборот. Другими словами, у вас должно быть условное interface IMenuItem {}, далее class ButtonMenuItem : IMenuItem {}, TextMenuItem : IMenuItem {} и т.д., а уже имея это, у вас должна быть коллекция, условно List<IMenuItem> MenuItems, которая заполняется уже этими объектами с нужными данными (MenuItems.Add(new ButtonMenuItem{ Title = "Профиль", Action = ... })). Надеюсь поняли мой посыл...

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо за развернутые ответы!)

@evo Спасибо за ответ!
